# In C#, how can i get a label to display multiple results without using additional labels?

Tags: c#, output, windows-forms-designer, fibonacci, label

My current code is as follows:

```
private void btnEXE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 1;
    int sum = 1;

    do
    {
        sum = num1 + num2;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = sum:

        lblOUT.Text = Convert.ToString(num2);
        while (sum <= 100);
    }
```

When I run the program, it gives me only a result of 144.
What I need the program to do is list every result in between 0 and 100 then output every result into a single label.
BTW this is the Fibonacci sequence.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: empty the lblOut.Text before the do, and the `lblOut.Text += Convert.ToString(num2) + Environment.NewLine;` to assign more info to the label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lblOUT.Text += Convert.ToString(num2) + Environment.NewLine;
```

That should be it

Comment: nonion. Thanks man i was ready to rip my hair out of my head, i think i might of missed class that day for the envirnoment.newline part. Thanks again you are my life savor

Comment: hey one more question for you (if you dont mind ^_^) The program lists everything now (which is want i desired) but the last value of 144 is being listed (which i dont want). should i change the "while (sum <= 100)" to "while (sum <= 89)". or is that just side stepping from what the actual solution should be?

Comment: If you want, you can just add a check if num2 >=143. If it is then don't display it :P

Comment: No worries! Happy Holidays to you too!

Answer (score 2):

Among many solutions, a simple one would be to use `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
do
{
   ...
   sb.AppendFormat("{0} ", num2);
}
while (sum <= 100)

lblOUT.Text = sb.ToString();
```

You could also store the numbers in a list and use `String.Join` among other solutions.

Comment: Wow, Bradley, thanks for the help, but i am a beginner at C# and i have not gone over "StringBuilder" yet so i do not know what it is exactly. I guess i should have stated my experience before i posted. But regardless i am not going to say it wasn't what i was looking for, so thank you for your help i appreciate it.

Comment: @SprJD7903 `StringBuilder` is a more efficient way to create long, dynamic strings (using `+` is not memory-efficient). Not something you have to worry about at this level, but it also makes for more idiomatic code in this case. You can check out its documentation at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx